# How to remove this arrow in the Toolbar on mainActivity Layout?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, fragment

Some weeks ago, I added this `Toolbar`. I need it for a swipe tab layout.
But if I install the apk, there is a back arrow in the top left corner.

[image: * Click * Here you can see the arrow which should be removed]

I don't know how I can remove it. Can you help me?

If you need any other layouts or classes, please ask me. I will edit the question.

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here the

> styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>

<style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">

</style>

<style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Please try to search for your answer before asking, I typed "android actionbar arrow remove" into google, and the answer was on the first link.

Comment: @barotia 90% of this answers are wrong

Comment: Then use the remaining 10%.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the arrow's presence, I'm assuming you set your `Toolbar` as the `ActionBar`.

If so, the fix is very simple. Simply call

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

AFTER you have called `setActionBar(yourToolbar)` to ensure there are no null pointer issues